# Livox SDK2 Mid360 get point cloud data in spherical coordinate and other configurations

Tags: spherical-coordinate

I tried to run quick start example provided in Livox SDK2 github repository, and the default point-cloud data type was in Cartesian coordinate (x, y, z, etc.)

Is there any approach that I can get the Spherical coordinate (d, theta, phi, etc.)? I cannot see any instruction on how to set data format in Livox's document.

Also I am wondering if there is any approach to modify the sampling rate of Mid360 device.